# XSLT - Conditional count the number of occurrences with a different child node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have following XML:

```
<problem>
 <problemID>1117</problemID>
 <file>/Admin/moc_/test/src/test.cpp</file>
 <code>XXXX</code>
 <message>Example</message>
 <citingStatus>Analyze</citingStatus>
 <severity>Unexpected</severity>
</problem>
<problem>
 <problemID>1118</problemID>
 <file>/Admin/moc_/test/src/test.cpp</file>
 <code>XXXX</code>
 <message>Example</message>
 <citingStatus>Analyze</citingStatus>
 <severity>Unexpected</severity>
</problem>
<problem>
 <problemID>1119</problemID>
 <file>/Admin/test/src/test.cpp</file>
 <code>XXXX</code>
 <message>Example</message>
 <citingStatus>Analyze</citingStatus>
 <severity>Unexpected</severity>
</problem>
<problem>
 <problemID>1120</problemID>
 <file>/Admin/moc_/test/src/test.cpp</file>
 <code>XXXX</code>
 <message>Example</message>
 <citingStatus>Analyze</citingStatus>
 <severity>Critical</severity>
</problem>
<problem>
 <problemID>1121</problemID>
 <file>/Admin/XXX/test/src/test.cpp</file>
 <code>XXXX</code>
 <message>Example</message>
 <citingStatus>Analyze</citingStatus>
 <severity>Unexpected</severity>
</problem>
```

I want to Count the number of occurrence which are not containing file name as "moc_" and have severity label as "Unexpected"

XSLT tag used is:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(problem[file[contains(.,'moc_')]] and [severity[.='Unexpected']])"/>
```

Using the above tag throws an error. I can individual calculate the count but not with and condition.

Comment: XSLT Tag used is : <xsl:value-of select="count(problem[file[contains(.,'moc_')]] and [severity[.='Unexpected']])"/>

Comment: You can modify your question for add this information into it.

Answer (score 1):

Try either:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(problem[file[contains(.,'moc_')]][severity='Unexpected'])"/>
```

or:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(problem[file[contains(.,'moc_')] and severity='Unexpected'])"/>
```

---

Note that:

```
[severity[.='Unexpected']]
```

can be stated simply as:

```
[severity='Unexpected']
```